# How to dismiss suggestions at top of keyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard

I am using a textfield with a keyboard. The words that are typed into the textField do not nescesarily need to exist because names are allowed to be typed in that the dictionary may not recognize. This is a problem. The suggestions at the top of the keyboard correct the name if it is not common. I know this is probably a built in feature in Xcode but for some reason I don't see it. How do I dismiss the suggestions at the top of the keyboard?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. That is Obj-C. I need to use Swift.

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you use. You can even do it in storyboard, if you are creating your textField there.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I didn't see the 2nd answer. This is a duplicate.